# Why the compiler complains about ambiguity

Tags: c++

In the below code compiler complains about ambiguity. Why? Clearly I'm passing non const non & object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<class T>
string toStr(const T& obj)
{
    return obj.toStr();
}

template<class T>
string toStr(T val)
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}
struct A
{
  string toStr(){return "A";}  
};
int main()
{
    A a;

    cout << toStr(static_cast<const A&>(a)) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to compile it on different compilers. Effect is the same.
I've even tried to cast it to the desired const & type. Nope.

```
cout << toStr(static_cast<const A&>(a)) << '\n';
```

Edit:

```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:35:18: error: call of
> overloaded ‘toStr(const A&)’ is ambiguous    35 |     cout <<
> toStr(static_cast<const A&>(a)) << '\n';
>       |             ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ main.cpp:17:8: note: candidate: ‘std::string toStr(const T&) [with T = A; std::string
> = std::__cxx11::basic_string]’    17 | string toStr(const T& obj)
>       |        ^~~~~ main.cpp:23:8: note: candidate: ‘std::string toStr(T) [with T = A; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string]’    23
> | string toStr(T val)
>       |        ^~~~~
```

And what's really frustrating about this is this line from error msg:
error: call of

> overloaded ‘toStr(const A&)’ is ambiguous
> How can this^^^ be ambigous if there is exactly one function with such signature?

Comment: Please include the complete error message in the question.

Comment: binding to const reference is as good as making a copy concerning overload resolution. The template is not relevant. (Also note that `string toStr(const T& obj)` cannot call `obj.toStr` because its not a const method)

Comment: What's the logic here? How is the compiler supposed to choose overloads? The closest thing you can do is overload on `const T &` vs `T &&`, which would compile, but choosing between `.toStr()` and `std::to_string(...)` based on that still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Both function templates are equally valid candidates. It seems you want [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), which doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: Unrelated but `A::toStr` should be const.

Comment: what do you want to achive by providing those two overloads?

Comment: Oh and because in the first variant, because `obj` is a reference to a constant object, `obj.toStr()` will not work because `A::toStr` is not callable on constant objects.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've provided error msgs

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai this is an example from the interview. Task was, to make it compile.

Comment: remove the `string toStr(T val)` overload is the fix and decalre the member function as `const`

Comment: if I was the interviewer you would already pass the task once you explained me why `using namespace std;` is better removed

Comment: there is no `cout << toStr(static_cast<const A&>(a)) << '\n';` in the code. Details matter. Please make sure the error matches the code you show

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai If only such questions were asked sure, but that particular question wasn't asked on that particular interview. I think what they meant now when I think about it is that converting value from lvalue to & is considered trivial and indeed solution was to remove one of the definitions.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai in edits I've provided further explanation with this code. But I've edited now the OC.

Comment: They probably wanted to hear about SFINAE and SFINAE-friendliness (`requires`, `concept`s, etc).

Answer (score 5):

In

```cpp
cout << toStr(a) << '\n';
```

you pass an lvalue of type `A` to `toStr()`.

It can now convert it to `const A&` to match

```cpp
const T& obj
```

or copy it to an `A` to match

```cpp
T val
```

None is more specialized than the other, hence the ambiguity.

Note that `A::toStr()` should be `const` qualified to be of use in the `string toStr(const T& obj)` version.

You could then add some constraints to select the correct overload, like checking if the type has a `toStr` member function:

```cpp
template <class, class = void>
struct has_toStr : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct has_toStr<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().toStr())> >
    : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
inline constexpr bool has_toStr_v = has_toStr<T>::value;

template <class T>
std::string toStr(const T& obj)
    requires has_toStr_v<T>
{
    return obj.toStr();
}

template <class T>
std::string toStr(T val)
    requires(not has_toStr_v<T>)
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}
```

Comment: It now reads "it can now [...] convert [an lvalue of type `A`] to an `A`"... @463035818_is_not_an_ai said it best: "binding to const reference is as good as making a copy concerning overload resolution".

Comment: @TedLyngmo See my edit when I cast to const T&. Now the error gets really ridiculous.

Comment: @Nelfeal I made a small adjustment

Comment: @DeborahC You need to make it `A::toStr() const`

Answer (score 2):

By-reference vs by-value parameters can't be used to disambiguate overloads. (At best you can use different kinds of references, e.g. `const T &` vs `T &&`, but it's irrelevant here.)

The issue here is the functions not being SFINAE-friendly (i.e. the function body being invalid for a specific `T` is not enough to reject that overload during overload resolution).

You need to spell out the conditions explicitly, e.g. using `requires`:

```
template <typename T> 
std::string toStr(const T &obj)
requires requires{{obj.toStr()} -> std::convertible_to<std::string>;}
{
    return obj.toStr();
}

template <typename T>
requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
std::string toStr(T val)
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}
```

I've also made some cosmetic changes. You also must `const`-qualify `A`'s `toStr()`.

---

Before C++20 it would look like this:

```
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_convertible_v<decltype(std::declval<const T &>().toStr()), std::string>,
        std::nullptr_t
    > = nullptr
> 
std::string toStr(const T &obj)
{
    return obj.toStr();
}

template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
> 
std::string toStr(T val)
{
    return std::to_string(val);
}
```

Comment: I like your constraints better than my old-school ones :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Mhm, was about to comment about the vintage use of `void_t`. :P

Comment: I've just gotten used to using `std::void_t` :-)

Comment: requires requires << Can C++ get any more ridiculous?
I of course appreciate the answer but by looking at that function we have actually more code to describe the function then the actual function body. C++ is really going down hill.

Comment: @DeborahC Downhill compared to *what*? The syntax looked way worse before C++20, see edit. The first `requires` precedes a bool expression controlling whether the function should be enabled. Then the second `requires{...}` returns a bool, true if the code in braces compiles. The latter can be abstracted away to a `concept`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Downhill compared to what? Strange question. But I suppose if I should answer it, then I would say, to itself really. Also compared with other languages, like Rust for example, the way C++ "implements" concepts seems so clunky and so verbose that it looks just to verbose.

Comment: @DeborahC Mhm, my point is that "downhill" means "worse compared to itself in the past". I'd understand if the syntax was nicer pre-C++20, but it wasn't. I kinda concur that `requires requires` looks wonky the first time you see it, but once you understand why it is like this, you get used to it (it's similar to `noexcept(noexcept(...))` we had before). If you don't like two `requires` in a row, move the condition to a `concept`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the full message not only the first line: `toStr(const A&): candidate` is ambiguous with `toStr(T val): candidate`.

Given `toStr(a)`, how would you choose among both? Pass by reference or by value? Ambiguous.

Trying to enforce the type by the use of `static_cast<const A&>` will not change anything, pass by reference or by value?

In general don't overload functions with pass-by-ref with pass-by-value or the converse, this leads to ambiguity.

Comment: Surely this: static_cast<const A&> states the intent of the programmer that the overload by ref should be used. Asking questions like:
"Trying to enforce the type by the use of static_cast<const A&> will not change anything, pass by reference or by value?" whilst already have the answered prepared is just silly. If I cast to const & it means that I want the "by ref" overload not by value.

Comment: Your intent is just to convert a given typed value into another one, but the semantic of the language may use some possible conversion to find candidates. There is no difference between a "variable" and a reference to it (`int a; int &b=a;` makes a and b absolutely indistinguishable). Constness in this will not change anything as a const ref can be used for a by-copy passing and a by-const-ref passing.

Comment: fair enough, but this is very counterintuitive.